# Error while creating a project in vue

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

[When I do "vue create project_name", I get this error, Click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoBnv.png)

Can anyone please help me out to sort this issue? Even I tried reinstalling my node js and vue.

**FYI**: node version is >10 , npm version >6 and vue >3

Comment: share that json file in which you written `"istanbul"` ?

Comment: No, I didnt modify anything anywhere. I just installed node js with npm then installed vue and finally tried to create a vue project. I dont know why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

OMG! issue got fixed in a single npm command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```